# One-to-Many relation definition: correct interpretation of the relationship direction

Tags: database-design, one-to-many, entity-relationship, data-modeling

I have a trouble about the interpretation of the "direction" of One-to-Many relation. Imagine the relation  `Person:City` between `Person` and `City` which describes the unique residence of each individual. A *person* can live only in one *city* and each *city* is inhabited by a lot of *persons*, hence possible tuples are `(p1,c1),(p2,c1),(p3,c1)`. I found two different definitions of this kind of rel:

1. Person:City is a **One-to-Many** relation because same instances of City participate more times to different instance of relation (eg. reference [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561))
2. Person:City is a **Many-to-One** relation because one row in table `City` (eg. `c1`)  may be linked with many rows in table `Person`, but one row in table `Person` is linked to only one row in table `City` (eg. reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)))

My doubt is about semantic: does *many* refer to *(i)* `City` for multiple participation of identical instances to the relation or refer to *(ii)* `Person` since different people are linked to same city?

Although that definition probably does not affect the structure of data, sometimes could lead to misunderstandings. 
Which is the correct one?

Comment: I think option 1. can be interpreted as one person lives in one city at a point in time, but for another instance of the relation i.e. at a different point in time could have lived in a different city, hence one (person) - to - many (cities). Option 2. is the usual interpretation that Many (people) live in one (city) and one (city) can have many (people) living in it.  So option 1 is only valid if you qualify it with the time dimension. Hope this helps.

Comment: @vmachan imagine that there is not a time dimension, I think this is not the point. Reading the definition in [first reference] (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561), it seems like "many" refers to the multiple participation of an instance of a city to the relationship table (eg. `(p1,c1),(p2,c1),(p3,c1)`)...and it's ok, since in that city live more individuals. My doubt is: does _many_ refer to City for multiple participation of identical instances or refer to Person since different people are linked to same city?

Comment: In your case, I would think that the multiple refers to Persons (many) living in a city (one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, Person:City is a many-to-one relationship.  More precisely, each city is associated with zero or more people (one-city-to-many-people), and each person is associated with exactly one city (one-person-to-one-city).  Both cardinalities are significant, but we simplify it to one-to-many since one-to-one in the opposite direction is assumed (else it would be many-to-many which we would decompose into multiple one-to-many relationships).

Note that the cardinality doesn't so much indicate row linkage as it describes the association between the Person and City domains.  Rows are physical structures while cardinality describes logical relations.  The difference is significant when using different physical formats than normalized tables, e.g. some DBMSs support multivalued attributes or may display data as graphs rather than tables.

I couldn't find the usage you described in your first reference, but regardless it's not a tutorial I would recommend to anyone.

Comment: Ok for the point about cardinality vs. physical structure. 
My doubt was about semantic. I wasn't understanding if **many** referred to (i) __*City*__ (for multiple participation of identical instances to the relation) or to (ii) __*Person*__ since different people are linked to same city.
According to your answer, the answer is _(ii)_, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with the cardinality in option 2.